# How to solve docker related issue with /bin/sh: node-pre-gyp: not found?

Tags: node.js, windows, docker, node-pre-gyp

A day ago I began to learn about Docker on my own. So I downloaded the app to my Windows 10 desktop and began the tutorial they recommended through the app. At one point they ask me to create a docker file with the following content:

`FROM node:12-alpine
   WORKDIR /app
   COPY . .
   RUN yarn install --production
   CMD ["node", "/app/src/index.js"]`

which I did to path: `D:\docker_stuff\app` under name "Dockerfile" with no extension. Next they ask me to run this command "docker build -t getting-started ." and here is where I am having issues as the command throws errors like:

`D:\docker_stuff\app>docker build -t getting-started .
    Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.673MB
    Step 1/5 : FROM node:12-alpine
     ---> 7a48db49edbf
    Step 2/5 : WORKDIR D:\docker_stuff\app
     ---> Using cache
     ---> 44ba6501de00
    Step 3/5 : COPY . .
     ---> 44164775d408
    Step 4/5 : RUN yarn install --production
     ---> Running in 5df554d6bac8
    yarn install v1.22.4
    [1/4] Resolving packages...
    [2/4] Fetching packages...
    info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
    info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
    [3/4] Linking dependencies...
    [4/4] Building fresh packages...
    info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
    error /D:docker_stuffapp/node_modules/bcrypt: Command failed.
    Exit code: 127
    Command: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
    Arguments:
    Directory: /D:docker_stuffapp/node_modules/bcrypt
    Output:
    /bin/sh: node-pre-gyp: not found`

What I tried:

1. Installed node

`D:\docker_stuff\app>node -v
v12.16.3;`

2. Installed npm

`D:\docker_stuff\app>npm -v
6.14.4;`

3. Ran command independently: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build which throws a lot more issues:

`D:\docker_stuff\app>node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
    node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.14.0
    node-pre-gyp info using node@12.16.3 | win32 | x64
    node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download
    node-pre-gyp ERR! install error
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: 101-app package.json is not node-pre-gyp ready:
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack package.json must declare these properties:
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack binary.module_name
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack binary.module_path
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack binary.host
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at validate_config (C:\Users\KahnTrevor\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\versioning.js:220:15)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Object.module.exports.evaluate (C:\Users\KahnTrevor\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\versioning.js:279:5)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at install (C:\Users\KahnTrevor\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\install.js:241:31)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Object.self.commands.<computed> [as install] (C:\Users\KahnTrevor\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\node-pre-gyp.js:52:37)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at run (C:\Users\KahnTrevor\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\bin\node-pre-gyp:82:30)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\KahnTrevor\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\bin\node-pre-gyp:134:1)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
    node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\KahnTrevor\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
    node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd D:\docker_stuff\app
    node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.3
    node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.14.0
    node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
    101-app package.json is not node-pre-gyp ready:
    package.json must declare these properties:
    binary.module_name
    binary.module_path
    binary.host`

4. Modified the package.json file from the git project where I added line <"bcrypt": "^3.0.6",> under "dependencies": { ;
5. Python is installed.

I feel that there might be an issue with the package.json file rather than my desktop, but I don't know for sure and if that is the issue how can I fix it? I know I'm a noob but could anyone provide me with some guidance?

Comment: What exact tutorial are you following?

Comment: The command in "Step 2/5" in your first output doesn't match the second line of your Dockerfile; are both lines exactly what you have on your system?

Comment: @DanielOcando I am following the docker learn program which is found in the docker meniu on desktop http://localhost/tutorial/our-application/

Comment: @DavidMaze actually the content of my dockerfile is
`FROM node:12-alpine
WORKDIR D:\docker_stuff\app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install --production
CMD ["node", "/app/src/index.js"]`

Comment: You can use the "edit" link to fix the incorrect code in your question.

Comment: The documentation is here: https://github.com/docker/getting-started

Comment: @DavidMaze i am not sure what you mean here : "You can use the "edit" link to fix the incorrect code in your question. – David Maze 2 hours ago"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"bcrypt": "^3.0.6"` requires python to be installed and the image you used in your Dockerfile `node:12-alpine` is a very minimal image for nodejs.

Either you use an ubuntu image and install python to the container you are building or you can use [bcryptjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs) instead.

You can add <"bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",> or just run `npm i bcryptjs`.

It says on the `README.md` of `bcyptjs` that it will be 30% slower than `bcrypt` but you won't have to worry about python dependecy on your app.

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded `zone.js` from `0.10.3` to `0.11.0` and I faced this issue, revert back resolved my issue.